# Asymmetric binary relations, my code is not working good

Tags: prolog

This is my code:

```
binary_relations(x,y) .
binary_relations(y,z) .

asymmetric :-
  not(symmetric) .

symmetric :-
  binary_relations(X,Y) ,
  binary_relations(Y,X) .
```

Everything is true and program is working in good way, but if I write:

```
binary_relations(x,y).
binary_relations(y,y).
binary_relations(y,z).
```

Program is false.

What I need to do is asymmetric binary relations as you can see. Anybody help? How can I figure out this situation?

For start you have to write: asymmetric.

Comment: You should use the standard `\+/1` instead of `not/1`.

Comment: Can you give an example of a query that gives an unexpected result?

Comment: Hi, I'm not programmer I don't know what does it mean \+/1 not/1. All I know is that I have to do asymmetric binary relations, so I'm trying everything :-(

Comment: Don't worry. It was just a suggestion. That is not a problem. But is not clear from your question what means that "program is working in good way" and then "program is false". Can you show us the exact output that you find problematic?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I don't really know how to explain for you. Asymmetric function is not symmetric. Symmetric is (A, B) and (B, A) is the same when you going forward and backwards. Asymmetric is not. (B, A) and (A, B) is false. Asymmetric is (A,B) and (B,C). I hope you understand me, maybe I'm wrong :-(

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation this is definition from Wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following knowledge base that **explicitly** describes three binary relations `r1/2`, `r2/2` and `r3/3`.

```
r1(a,a).
r1(a,b).
r1(b,a).
r1(a,c).
r1(c,a).

r2(a,b).
r2(a,c).

r3(a,a).
r3(b,a).
r3(a,c).
```

It is obvious to see that `r1/2` is symmetric, `r2/2` and `r3/2` are both antisymmetric and `r2/2` is the only asymmetric of the three.

Let's try to express that in natural language and then using logic. A relation `R` is symmetric if two objects `X`,`Y` such that `R(X,Y)` is true, but `R(Y,X)` is false do not exist.

```
symmetric(R):-
    \+ (call(R, X, Y), \+ call(R, Y, X)).
```

A relation `R` is asymmetric if there are no two objects (not necessarily distinct) such that both `R(X,Y)` and `R(Y,X)` are true.

```
asymmetric(R):-
    \+ (call(R, X, Y), call(R, Y, X)).
```

And third, a relation `R` is antisymmetric if both `R(X,Y)` and `R(Y,X)` being true implies that `X` and `Y` are the same entity (in other words: there are no two distinct objects `X`, `Y` such that both `R(X,Y)` and `R(Y,X)` are true).

```
antisymmetric(R):-
    \+ (call(R, X, Y), call(R, Y, X), Y \== X).
```

And some queries:

```
?- symmetric(r1).
true.

?- symmetric(r2).
false.

?- symmetric(r3).
false.

?- asymmetric(r1).
false.

?- asymmetric(r2).
true.

?- asymmetric(r3).
false.

?- antisymmetric(r1).
false.

?- antisymmetric(r2).
true.

?- antisymmetric(r3).
true.
```